# Under the "Questions" tab of the main site, what does the "faq" option really mean?

Tags: support, site-attributes

The mouse over states "questions with the most links".  Does this mean questions that are most often linked to, or that the questions themselves contain the most links?  Either way, it seems a little confusing.  I expected to find "frequently asked questions" here.  Is link count intended as a measure of how often users are asking these questions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure its questions with the most internal links pointing to it. So if one question points to another, it gains +1 to its "faq score".

Comment: The answers to this question seem to contradict. Can someone provide a source or some kind of confidence?

Comment: David is head of development... I'd take his word

Comment: Sounds good to me :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's questions with the most *internal* links pointing to it (as in, from one question to another).  With enough activity, it becomes a sort of FAQ because the questions are typically linked as a reference in another answer, or closed as duplicate of the FAQ question.